# Getting repository information using pygithub3 for Python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I'm trying to access the language used in each repository given a Github username. In order to do this, so far my python code is:

```
from pygithub3 import Github

username = raw_input("Please enter a Github username: ")
password = raw_input("Please enter the account password: ")

gh = Github(login=username, password = password)

get_user = gh.users.get()

user_repos = gh.repos.list().all().language

print user_repos
```

However, the list object apparently doesn't have any language attribute, so I don't know how to access that information. Does anyone have any help?

Comment: what do you get with "user_repos = gh.repos.list().all()" ?

Comment: Just the name of all the repos, in a list.

Comment: have you been able to do the same with ssh keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this man, it worked for me:

```
from pygithub3 import Github

username = raw_input("Please enter a Github username: ")
password = raw_input("Please enter the account password: ")

gh = Github(login=username, password = password)

get_user = gh.users.get()

user_repos = gh.repos.list().all()

for repo in user_repos:
    print repo.language
```

Comment: However, just to add to this question, the output is a whole bunch of strings one after the other - is there anyway either to convert the output to a single list, or to count the number of similar outputs (e.g. Python, C#)?

Comment: Disregard that, I figured it out using the code below:

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the information, and get a count of each type as well:

```
from pygithub3 import Github

#declare variables
python = 0
cplusplus = 0
javascript = 0
ruby = 0
java = 0

#user input
username = raw_input("Please enter your Github username: ")
password = raw_input("Please enter your account password: ")

user = raw_input("Please enter the requested Github username: ")

#Connect to github
gh = Github(login=username, password = password)

get_user = gh.users.get(user)

user_repos = gh.repos.list(user = user).all()

#Count language in each repo
for repo in user_repos:

if repo.language == "Python":
    python = python + 1

elif repo.language == "JavaScript":
    javascript = javascript + 1

elif repo.language == "Ruby":
    ruby = ruby + 1

elif repo.language == "C++":
    cplusplus = cplusplus + 1

elif repo.language == "Java":
    java = java + 1


#Print results
print "Number of Python repositories: " + str(python)
print "Number of Javascript repositories: " + str(javascript)
print "Number of Ruby repositories: " + str(ruby)
print "Number of C++ repositories: " + str(cplusplus)
print "Number of Java repositories: " + str(java)
```