# gitpython list all repositories

Tags: python, gitpython

Folks,
  I keep having trouble finding documentation on how to list all git repositories for an organization using `gitpython`.
  I would like to grab a list of all current repositories we have in bitbucket/github, but fail to find it in the docs.
  I've found [pygithub3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083477/getting-repository-information-using-pygithub3-for-python) example, but nothing for `gitpython`.  Since I need to access bitbucket repos as well, pygithub3 wont work in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gitpython` is a library for manipulating the version-control software `git` itself and has little to do with online services like Github or Bitbucket. In order to interface either of those, you will need to use libraries like `pygithub3` and `python-bitbucket` as both offer completely different APIs for retrieving organizations, let alone repositories themselves. `gitpython` will come in handy should you want to clone and manipulate a fork of a repository from one of these online services.

Your hypothetical workflow might look something like this:

1. Retrieve repositories of Github-hosted organization `xyz-corp` using `pygithub3`, or alternatively, the repositories of Bitbucket-hosted organization `uvw-corp` using `python-bitbucket`
2. Clone the repositories locally using `gitpython`
3. Manipulate the files
4. Commit and push your changes back to the remote, Github-or-Bitbucket-hosted repository using `gitpython`