# pygithub3 authentication with ssh keys

Tags: python, pygithub

Folks,
  Trying to use pygithub3 to connect to our github repos.  I need to use local ssh keys to make the connection, not tokens or u/p as in the docs.  Is this possible?

The [doc](http://pygithub.readthedocs.org/en/latest/github.html) do not seem to list the option to auth in with `id_rsa`

I see [another slashdot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083477/getting-repository-information-using-pygithub3-for-python) using u/p auth.  Is there a way to feed in a custom `id_rsa` file to use?

Comment: What about the linked example is "slashdot"?

Comment: `pygithub3` does not offer `ssh` key authentication because the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) only supports `Basic` and `OAUTH2` authentication.